# Cirrus Branded Cards

Tags: credit-card

I just got a Cirrus branded card, and it begins with 00. I could not find anything similar to this on a BIN list. Is there any reliable way to determine if a card is Cirrus?

Comment: Did this Cirrus branded car magically appear in the mail? or did you apply for it? or is it linked to your existing bank account?

Comment: Actively got it myself. I have like 30 credit cards and a 780, so at this point I'm pre approved for just about everything.

Comment: So you went to the Cirrus website, filled out an application, got approved, an now have it in the mail. But you don't trust it?

Comment: No, I trust it. I just don't know how to verify its authenticity if someone were to use a similar card on my website.

Comment: It doesn't follow Luhns checksum, and it has leading zeros, instead of the 52-55 I'd expect.

Comment: What type of card is this?  (credit card, debit card, ATM card, etc.)  Which country are you in?

Answer (score 2):

[Cirrus](http://www.mastercard.com/ie/consumer/cirrus-card.html) is the inter-bank network operated by Mastercard. The logo looks similar to the Mastercard logo, but not quite.

It is **not** a credit card. This is an ATM card and can be used as a debit card at stores that allow using Mastercard ATM network for purchases. It is not supposed to be used as a credit card, so you will not be able to use it online.

Cards may have variable amount of digits in their numbers. Specifically Maestro cards (Mastercard ATM/Debit brand) can have 12-19 digits. So in your case it looks like the card number has 14 digits, with preceding zeroes.

Comment: But it is a credit card. It is a Cirrus branded card with a line of credit extended by Citibank. But it makes sense that it cannot be used online.

Comment: Cirrus wouldn't be the 'brand' even if it were a credit card - it's the *network*. Are you sure Citibank didn't just connect this to a bank account with a line of credit backing overdrafts or heloc or similar?

Answer (score 0):

According to the wikipedia page on [ISO/IEC 7812](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_7812#Major_industry_identifier), which is the international standard for credit card numbers, the leading digit of the credit card can be a zero. While the leading zeros are not common, they may have been held for a future use. It's possible that your credit card is one such case of this future use.

The wikipedia page linked above also states, under the "Bank Identifier Number" section, that the official register of numbers is not available to the public. It would seem that the only reliable way to verify that the card is valid, would be to call the card issuer and ask them if the number is valid.

Comment: I'm certain it's valid. It doesn't even follow Luhns checksum though, which probably is going to break some websites, unless this was done deliberately to prevent its use online.

Comment: @EvanHendler It might be worth asking your issuer why this is the case - not following Luhns would certainly make it hard to use online